# What methods make it possible to access the source code?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

There are several ways to access the source code of a library from within a Ruby code that require/loads that library. Among these ways, some read the library file directly and parse it. Others access the source through some built in methods that provide information about the source (such as the abstract syntax tree). In a situation where I have no access to directly read the content of the file (as in the former ways), the only way to access the source would be through accessing the built-in methods that provide the information. By redefining these methods to do something else, I will completely loose access to the source code. What are the minimum set of methods such that if I redefine them to something else, I will completely loose access to the source code of the library on an external file?

---

**To rephrase the question**

Suppose:

- There is a user that can write any Ruby code in file A.
- There is a static Ruby file B written by me, which loads file A and calls the main routine defined in A, and also defines some classes/methods that the user can use in A.
- The user does not have +r (read) or +w (write) permission to B.

Which (standard Ruby) methods do I have to redefine (nullify) or remove by writing so in file B in order to make it impossible for the user to access the source written in file B (via whatever code the user can write in file A) when I run file B?

There are some libraries like sorcerer, pry, that can extract the source code of the methods it has access to. There must be some primitive commands within plain Ruby that these libraries rely upon to make it possible for them to access the source code. What are the methods that make this kind of things possible?

If you don't know the full answer but know how a particular library extracts the source of some method, then that will still help.

Comment: I think you can define some abstract class or something similar to interface in Java, that does not implement anything. The interface will publicly access from the external components. Then you can inherit the abstract class to implement it internally.

Comment: When redefining such methods, you could make use of the `Module#alias_method` to make sure you have a "copy" of the original method you're modifying. http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/alias_method

Comment: _system_, _backtick_, _fork/exec_, etc., are going to have to be disabled.

Comment: @WayneConrad Even if the user is not a superuser and does not have the +r or +w permission to file B?

Comment: @sawa, As far as I know, the Ruby executable must be readable in order for the ruby interpreter to run it.

Comment: Most cases of how it is done in PRY are in this file:  https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/master/lib/pry/method.rb

Comment: @WayneConrad Thanks for the information. I changed the question a bit. What if the user does not have any access to file B?

Comment: You will get a LoadError if you do not have read permission on the file, even if it is required from another file or library.

Comment: @ShawnBalestracci The user only has permission to file A, but not B. I have permission to both files. I run file B, which loads file A.

Comment: @saw, If you run B, which then loads and runs A (via _require_, _load_, etc.), the code in A is running with *your* permissions.

Comment: @WayneConrad Yes. That is what I mean after I changed the question a bit.

Comment: Wait. You want to load a "plugin" (can't think of a better word), and then prevent it from reading the source code of your application, by doing some crazy sandboxing? Wouldn't it just be easier to sandbox the code in another process, use builtin/C level OS sandboxing features (I know Linux has them), and do some IPC?

Comment: @Linuxios Yes, you got the question correctly. I am not so good about the OS stuff. I use Ubuntu Linux. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @sawa:with a kernel extension like SELinux or AppArmour (the one Ubuntu comes with), you can restrict which files a proccess can access.

Comment: s/sourcerer/sorcerer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Ruby-only solutions can only use `source_location`, so just redefine this to return something like `['/some/empty/file', 1]`. C hacks to the interpreter don't use `source_location`, but you can prevent any use of C extensions by blocking/white-listing `require` and friends.

---

For one, to be able to execute a Ruby script, you have to be able to read it...

But back to the question. I know Sourcify doesn't use any mystical method besides a little method on Proc and Method called `source_location`, which gives the filename and line number were a method/proc is defined. I know from experience that this approach is very fragile, requires writing some sort of parser, and only sometimes works in legitimate situations. So, Sourcify is already out if you redefine `source_location` in B to return something like `/dev/null, line 0` and let Sourcify throw a not-Ruby-source exception.

From Pry's [source](https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/master/lib/pry/method.rb#L551-L566), it seems that Pry uses the same `source_location` approach, so two birds with one stone.

Now, there is another option for all of these libraries, which is to drop down to C and hack the interpreter to record source code. This is almost flawless. But we can still avoid the danger in one very simple way. Someone could include all of the code for Pry's method source in A. But you can't include inline C/C extensions without requiring a C library. So, the solution is obvious: Redefine `require` and `require_relative` and `load` to either not work, or to only allow certain libraries. This way, you can keep out the C hacks.

On MRI, there is no way (from Ruby code) besides `source_location` to do this. So there you go!

**Edit**: According to @banister, from MRI 2.0+ there is a `binding_of_caller` method builtin that could replace source location. Nuke this too. ;)

**Warning**: Ruby is not a good language for this. If you can metaprogram them, they can probably metaprogram you unless you're in a different process.

Comment: Thanks. I finally got an answer that is to the point. By nullifying `source_location`, do you think I can avoid access to the Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) as well?

Comment: @sawa what are you trying to do is extremely weird -- but messing with source_location is not going to be enough. A combination of binding_of_caller and Binding#eval("__FILE__") etc will return much the same info as source_location. Anyone with enough smarts will be able to get around any block u put in place, really, Ruby is *not* the language for this kind of thing, don't even try :)

Comment: @sawa: From what I can tell, you can only access the AST through a C extension, which cannot be loaded without control over the Ruby environment, or by using `require`.

Comment: @banister: I've never heard of `binding_of_caller` before. Is it part of core MRI Ruby?

Comment: @linuxios it's built-in from MRI 2.0+, but prior to that it was a C extension: https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller. Even without binding_of_caller you can still get the info you want using set_trace_func and recording the bindings as the code traces though

Comment: @banister I can nullify `set_trace_func`. I am asking what is the set of commands that I need to nullify.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very easy if you use the awesome 'method_source' gem by John Mair (the maker of Pry):
The method has to be implemented in Ruby (not C), and has to be loaded from a file (not irb).

Here's an example displaying the method source code in the Rails console with method_source:

```
  $ rails console
  > require 'method_source'

  # the following prints out the method code for #lookup in the Rails I18n Backend:

  > I18n::Backend::Simple.instance_method(:lookup).source.display
    def lookup(locale, key, scope = [], options = {})
      init_translations unless initialized?
      keys = I18n.normalize_keys(locale, key, scope, options[:separator])

      keys.inject(translations) do |result, _key|
        _key = _key.to_sym
        return nil unless result.is_a?(Hash) && result.has_key?(_key)
        result = result[_key]
        result = resolve(locale, _key, result, options.merge(:scope => nil)) if result.is_a?(Symbol)
        result
      end
    end
    => nil
```

The Ruby code which is displayed needs to come from a file which has been already loaded,
(obviously it has to be readable), and it needs to be native Ruby code (this does not work for compiled/linked libraries).

See also:

- https://rubygems.org/gems/method_source
- https://github.com/banister/method_source
- http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/